# Check if validation of model has been failed

Tags: laravel

I need to delete another model if current model has been failed on save.

trying:

```
$saved = $model->save(); // if validation fails the application has aborted

// never executes this    
if ( !$saved ) {
  $anotherModel->delete();
}
```

how do that?

Comment: Could you explain the code? So that we can figure out whats the problem is

Comment: I understand your question, ` $model->save()` suppose to return affected row if data was saved or false if failed. It seems the data is saved thats why` $saved` is returns true

Comment: If the save didn't go through you would get an exception thrown. So this check doesn't make much sense because !$saved will always evaluate as true.

Comment: @Alexandre Thebaldi can you do `dd($saved)`